# Git Clone in Jenkins with Personal Access Token idles forever

Tags: git, jenkins

We have an enterprise github running on a remote github server outside of our company network and need to use an https proxy to clone. We are not allowed to use password authentication, so either ssh (which is a no go due to proxy issues) or PAT.

On my command line, the command

```
git clone https://user:token@github.exampleco.com/org/repo.git
```

clones the repository no problem, and it takes about 5-10 seconds.

In Jenkins, the console output reads "cloning into directory-name" and then there's a spinning wheel that spins endlessly and this never resolves.

I am running this inside an execute shell script as the github plugin runs some commands that apparently still want to do password authentication, even when I feed it the PAT version of the url with no credentials, and I don't see a PAT authorization option in the add credentials modal.

To clarify the url given to the Jenkins plugin is:

```
https://user:token@github.exampleco.com/org/repo.git
```

and I get this sort of output:

```
No credentials specified
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://user:token@github.exampleco.com/org/repo.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://user@github.exampleco.com/org/repo.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
Setting http proxy: corporateproxy.com:8080
 > git fetch --tags --progress https://user@github.exampleco.com/org/repo.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from https://user@github.exampleco.com/org/repo.git
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:894)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1161)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1192)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:504)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1208)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:574)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:499)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1818)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress https://user@github.exampleco.com/org/repo.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: remote: Password authentication is not available for Git operations.
remote: You must use a personal access token or SSH key.
remote: See https://github.exampleco.com/settings/tokens or https://github.exampleco.com/settings/ssh
fatal: unable to access 'https://user@github.exampleco.com/org/repo.git': The requested URL returned error: 403

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2042)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1761)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$400(CliGitAPIImpl.java:72)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:442)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:892)
    ... 11 more
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
Finished: FAILURE
```

I do notice that the user:token@ is dropped in favor of simply user@ after the remote origin is configured. I tried running all of these commands manually in a shell and when I got to the second one, that is:

```
git fetch --tags --progress https://user:token@github.exampleco.com/org/repo.git
```

it also just idled forever like the clone command does.

Comment: Could you try with user:password instead user: token?

Comment: That wouldn't work. Password authentication is not allowed. I've found the solution and am in the process of adding an answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was that I needed to run as myself instead of as jenkins. Running as the user jenkins doesn't allow us to clone.

We can check who we are running as by putting the command `whoami` into the execute shell build step. If your `whoami` doesn't match your username (it is most likely that `whoami` will return jenkins as the username), we have some configuring to do.

Go to the jenkins home, select Manage Jenkins, then select Manage Nodes. Create a new node.

Give this new node one executor, choose "Only build jobs with label expressions matching this node" in usage, and give your project a unique label. Choose "Launch agent agents via SSH" in your launch method. Make your host `localhost`, and add your credentials (username and password) for logging into the machine you're using. Choose not to verify host keys, and select "Keep this agent online as much as possible" in availability, and save. You'll need to launch the agent.

Now go to your job. Under configure in the General tab, check "Restrict where this job can run" and enter that unique label. Save. Your job should now clone in precisely the same way as your command line git does.

This works on Mac, not sure of windows, but I assume it is basically the same.

Comment: Can I have the references? because your posted answer is bit unclear

Answer (score 6):

I found one more easy option to do this,

please refer to this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61104238/5108695

---

After some intense googling I found the answer, which proved to be a lot easier then I thought:

Apparently a personal access token can be used as a password, as far as Jenkins is concerned at least. I added new credentials to the credential manager, chose type 'username and password', put in a non-existing username ('user') and put the personal access token in the password field.

This way I could choose the credentials from the dropdown as I did before, and the project was cloned without issues

---