# Change jenkins pipeline to use github instead of gitlab

Tags: jenkins, github

I have a set of automated tests that are ran in a jenkins pipeline, testcode is located in gitlab. 
The section where I pull code from gitlab looks like this:

[image]

I use gitlab credentials that were already present there (since other project use the same gitlab credentials).

I use a simple jenkinsfile that is located in the test codebase to run the script from here. This is roughly how it looks:

```
  agent {
    kubernetes {
      defaultContainer 'jnlp'
      yaml """
        apiVersion: v1
        kind: Pod
        metadata:
          labels:
            application: auto_ish
        spec:
            containers:
              - name: node
                image: node:12.14.1
                command:
                - cat
                tty: true
      """
    }
  }
  stages {
    stage('Build') {
      steps {
        container('node') {
            sh '''
                npm install
            '''
        }
      }
    }

    stage('Test') {
      steps {
        container('node') {
          sh 'node_modules/.bin/wdio ./test/config/wdio.conf.acc.js --suite SmokeTest --mochaOpts.grep=@smoke' 
         }
      }
    }
```

**My problem:**

The codebase of my automated tests has recently been moved to github, and I have trouble getting it to work in jenkins. For github I have a personal access token  that I need to use, so no private key like I had for gitlab. I have tried adding this token to the credentials manager, but after adding it doesnt show up in the dropdown.

I followed some walkthroughs that told me to install github plugins for jenkins and then set my personal access token in jenkins configuration like this:

[image]

I tested the connection,and it worked.

From here on, I have no idea how to proceed. I just want to pull the code from the codebase to run the project. No need to trigger builds when code is pushed to github, since my tests are triggered when other jobs finish.

But since my credentials are not in the credentialsmanager, I cannot just add the new repo here. This also means I cannot refer to my jenkinsfile here.

I read somewhere I had to refer to my github project here:
[image]
I did this, butI think this will not be enough. I figure I need to pull the code from the new repo somewhere, but I have no idea where.

Which brings me to my question: where and how do I pull the code from my github repo, using the personal acces token/github server I specified?.

Comment: Basically you want to configure your `jenkins` instance so that it can build project from  github

Comment: I mean, Do you want to  setup `Jenkins` instance using `SSH key` so that Jenkins can access `github` repos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some intense googling I found the answer, which proved to be a lot easier then I thought:

Apparently a personal access token can be used like a password, as far as jenkins is concerned atleast. I added new credentials to the credential manager, chose type 'username and password', put in a non existing username ('user') and put the personal access token in the password field.

This way I could choose the credentials from the dropdown like I did before, and the project was cloned without issues

Comment: That will work only if your repo allows password access. Otherwise you will get "stderr: remote: Password authentication is not available for Git operations."

Answer (score 5):

You can configure `Jenkins` instance with `Github` with the help of `SSH` key

You Just have to create `SSH` public and private keys and past `public` key in

Github > Settings > SSH/GPC key > Add public key
Make sure you will not add any space and new line

Save and exit from Github

Now go to `Jenkins`
* Start to configure your project, or Go to `credentials` > `System` > `Global credentials` > `Add credentials` a page will open

- In `Kind` drop-down select `SSH Username with private key`
- Check private key radio button and then press `Add key` button, a textarea will open paste your private key in that textarea, Make sure you copy the private key and while pasting not adding any space in it. Make sure you select the whole key, `Begin` and `End` text of key also.

[image]

[image]

- Now Save and while Configuring Project `Source Code Management` tab, you will find credentials and a drop-down, select the new configured key from that dropdown `jenkinsSSH`.
- Make sure your clone your Github repo using `SSH` not `HTTPS`

[image]

and build the application. this will work

for more reference watch this video tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mGXGIOpKAos&list=PLhW3qG5bs-L_ZCOA4zNPSoGbnVQ-rp_dG&index=9

[Update]

To clone git repository using Personal Access Token, you can use following format

`https://user:token@github.exampleco.com/org/repo.git`
like

`git clone https://user:token@github.exampleco.com/org/repo.git`

there is one more question same as this, and he provided one solution, might help you

[Git Clone in Jenkins with Personal Access Token idles forever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56809684/git-clone-in-jenkins-with-personal-access-token-idles-forever)

please have a look

Comment: if having any issues please let me know, I will help you out

Comment: I'm afraid you missed what I said here: 'For github I have a personal access token that I need to use'. I do not want to use my own personal account for this, and the service account that is linked to the personal access token is out of my control.

Comment: I am afraid, for now, Jenkins is not able to pull repo on the basis of Personal Access Token, as per my knowledge.

Comment: Github server can only be used to configure hooks. 

Comment: I found this solution.